# getting values from URL to _GET values in htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a particular URL

```
www.domain.com/value/index.php?id=123
```

and i want to change that to something like

```
www.domain.com/index.php?id=123&pid=value
```

in htaccess

How do I go about doing so?

I've been trying alot of ways to get this but i cant seem to get the "value"

Hope someone can share some light

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} \id=([0-9]+?)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.+)$ $2?id=%1&pid=$1         [NC]
```

try this.